# Maintenance Tasks causes CPU to peg 100% utilization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, maintenance-plans

I do not believe the maintenance tasks themselves to be the primary issue here, however CheckDB and index rebuilds cause the server to become unresponsive w/ 100% cpu utilization.

It is on one specific database that this occurs. I can run the maintenance tasks on all databases but one with no issue.

I can also restore that database to another SQL Instance (dev or test) and run the operations there as well with no issue. It is only with respect to this one database call it `db01` on the production instance. I ran the consistency check for corruption on both the old (2008 + server 2008), as well as dev(2016 + server 2016) with no reports of corruption.

Does this prove out enough that the issue is with the production box/hardware versus my SQL Server configuration?

Comment: While experimenting the issue, can you run a sp_whoisactive to identify the session causing the issue (and what it is doing at that time).
You said both checkdb and index rebuild causes the issue ? You could try to run the checkdb with maxDOP set to 1 so you will still be able to access the instance (as a possible workaround)

Comment: Are you running native DBCC maintenance plan or [Ola's](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html) scripts? Try running this troubled DB in a separate job and monitor the server. Is the configuration same for the other server you restored this DB compared with your source server? Are you using MAXDOP setting with CHECKDB statement?  Also, you may need to check global MAXDOP setting too. As CHECKDB depends on factors like db size, system load, checkdb options, tempdb..

Comment: Do you have heap tables (tables without clustered indexes). I've seen them cause wild resource usage for some operations (when loads and loads of non-used space in them). So, I never trust those buggers...

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher, I'll give that a shot on this next run. 

Kris, I'm not using any maxdop setting, as it executes perfectly fine without one on the dev environment. We are running native maintenance plans. 

TiborKaraszi, there are some heap tables, but this is a vendor database, so I cannot modify the schema.